# Does programming to an interface help get rid of globals?

Tags: php, inheritance, design-patterns, interface, global-variables

Or is my interface the new "global"?  I'm trying to find a way to get rid of statements like:

```php
function someFunction()
{
    global $var1, $var3, $var4;
    //these are eventually assigned instantiated classes from an include
    ....
}
```

So far I am only coming up with interfaces.  I am thinking my code will only be a little looser, maybe a lot.  But if I really wanted to loosely couple after implementing an interface (or extending a class), couldn't I always create another level of abstraction between the interface and the inheriting classes with another abstract class or interface?

How can I start to get rid of globals other than rewriting an entire project?

Comment: In which language?

Comment: The language for this question is php.

Comment: I don't see how globals and interfaces are related... Globals are a bad way to share data, there are other (safer) ways to share data - which one is the right for you depends on your use-case.

Comment: Plus one to @alfasin. Read up on things like Dependency Injection and Composition.

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of globals is super simple and doesn't require introducing interface (or even classes). If you have code like presented:

```
function someFunction()
{
    global $var1, $var3, $var4;
    // ...
```

then you just need to replace it with:

```
function someFunction($var1, $var3, $var4)
{
    // ...
```

And done. No globals;)

EDIT
You will have to rewrite whole project. Replacing globals with eg. static variables will not really increase quality of your code. It is a global, just in different form.